Short story about gene editing
Only details I can remember include first-person narrator, a teenage boy. The household next door has a girl 6 feet 4 inches with blue eyes. She was gene edited.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There isn't really much here to go on.  Was the protagonist genengineered?  Was it common?  Where did you read this, was it in a magazine, an anthology, or online?

My immediate impulse is "Mr Boy" by James Patrick Kelly, but I don't remember Treemonisha's height being mentioned, and his other named friend is a dinosuar.

Mr. Boy sounds about right. But neither Amazon nor Alibris seem to carry it. Any suggestions where I can find it?

You can see all the publications of the story by looking it up on the ISFDB.

I have the story in the anthology Cyberpunk and there is a good summary on Wikipedia. Treemonisha's height is not mentioned in the story and neither is the colour of her eyes, so if you're sure about the girl being 6'4" with blue eyes this is not the story you remember.
